# INSERT query using stored procedure not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a form which allows users to report things. I am trying to use asp and an SQL stored procedure to run it but I can't get it to work!

Any help much appreciated!

This is the asp/vb:

```
Dim insertVictim__firstName
insertVictim__firstName = null
if(Request.form("firstName") <> "") then insertVictim__firstName = Request.form("firstName")

Dim insertVictim__surName
insertVictim__surName = null
if(Request.form("surName") <> "") then insertVictim__surName = Request.form("surName")

Dim insertVictim__Gender
insertVictim__Gender = null
if(Request.form("Gender") <> "") then insertVictim__Gender = Request.form("Gender")

Dim insertVictim__DOB
insertVictim__DOB = null
if(Request.form("DOB") <> "") then insertVictim__DOB = Request.form("DOB")

set insertVictim = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
insertVictim.ActiveConnection = MM_SecurityReporting_STRING
insertVictim.CommandText = "dbo.sp_insertIntoVictim"
insertVictim.Parameters.Append insertVictim.CreateParameter("@firstName", 200, 1,20,insertIncident__firstName)
insertVictim.Parameters.Append insertVictim.CreateParameter("@surName", 200, 1,20,insertIncident__surName)
insertVictim.Parameters.Append insertVictim.CreateParameter("@Gender", 200, 1,20,insertIncident__Gender)
insertVictim.Parameters.Append insertVictim.CreateParameter("@DOB", 200, 1,20,insertIncident__DOB)
insertVictim.CommandType = 4
insertVictim.CommandTimeout = 0
insertVictim.Prepared = true
insertVictim.Execute()
```

This is the SQL Stored Procedure:

```
USE [SecurityReporting]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_insertIntoVictim]    Script Date: 07/08/2013 16:59:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_insertIntoVictim]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @firstName varchar(20),
    @surName varchar(20),
    @Gender varchar(20),
    @DOB varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into tbl_victim (firstName, surName, Gender, DOB)
    values (@firstName, @surName, @Gender, @DOB)

END
```

Comment: "*I can't get it to work*" doesn't help us much. What happens? Is there an error?

Comment: Not related to your question, but storing the birth date as a varchar instead of date is a bad idea.

Comment: thanks for your comments, no error or anything! Just not inserting the values in to the table :(

Comment: How are you verifying that the records are not being inserted?  If you are using your asp application, that might not be the best approach.  I suggest querying your db directly.

Comment: i do verfiy by querying the database directly in sql management studio

Comment: 1) Remove any [`On Error Resume Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53f3k80h%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) statements from your script, 2) add [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), 3) Explicitly declare every variable using `Dim`, and 4) report back with your results.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to use the answer space, but I can't comment on posts yet. I wanted to first re-iterate Dan Bracuk's comment regarding the date datatype. That type of thing has given me more unnecessary grief.

Also, I wanted to recommend you use SQL Profiler. It is your best friend in these situations. Start up Profiler from SSMS, in your settings for your trace, filter by database name and even by login or user so you can reduce what displays to only the interaction between you/your application and the specified database.

Run your application and attempt to insert. View the results in Profiler. It will show you the information being passed so you can see if there is a data type mismatch or some other problem with the values being sent and being used by your stored procedure.

If nothing at all shows up, you'll at least know that the application is not hitting SQL Server at all. However, it looks to me like it probably is connecting but there is a problem with a value causing the insert to fail. If you do get results in your trace, select the result row where the SP is executed, and copy out the body of that result. Then, paste it into a New Query window in SSMS and just check to see what messages you get when you run it manually.

I hope this can help you. I know Profiler has rescued me from the brink more times than I can count. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

In your code above you're using your variables beginning with `insertVictim__`. However, down in your parameters passed, you're using `insertIncident__`.

(Example)

```
Dim insertVictim__firstName
insertVictim__firstName = null
if(Request.form("firstName") <> "") then insertVictim__firstName = Request.form("firstName")
```

If `insertVictim__` is the actual variable to be passed - which I'm guessing it is as it's referring the form, you'll never get anything as it's not actually being handed off to the procedure.

For example:

```
insertVictim.Parameters.Append insertVictim.CreateParameter("@firstName", 200, 1,20,insertIncident__firstName)
```

Should be:

```
insertVictim.Parameters.Append insertVictim.CreateParameter("@firstName", 200, 1,20,insertVictim__firstName)
```

(or Vice Versa depending on what you call)

Also - Are you including the adovbs.inc file?  If you had not, you would be getting errors as the commands would be unrecognized, but just throwing that out there.